# React native SQLite storage slow performance

Tags: react-native, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using SQLite in my React Native app, and I'm experiencing performance issues. Specifically, the SQLite queries are very slow. For instance, when the system runs and generates a list of 39 records, it initially displays quickly. However, after accessing the same list three times, it starts to slow down significantly. Is there anyone who can help me for faster performance?

need suggestion..
Any one able to help me out

Comment: You'll need to update your question with the relevant table layouts, the queries that you have measured(!) to be slow, and why you consider them to be slow. The question will be closed without further information.